# Plot R graph using JRI

Tags: java, r, jsp, ggplot2, jri

I was using JRI to plot a graph in JSP. If I use the below code, it works fine.

```
Rengine re = new Rengine (new String [] {"--vanilla"}, false, null);
re.eval("jpeg('<filename>')";
re.eval("plot(x,y)");
re.eval("dev.off()");
```

Instead if I use dotplot, the jpeg file is not getting generated.

```
Rengine re = new Rengine (new String [] {"--vanilla"}, false, null);
re.eval("jpeg('<filename>')";
re.eval("library(\"lattice\")");
re.eval("dotplot(y~x)");
re.eval("dev.off()");
```

In the above case the "< filename >" won't be created. Same issue if I use "ggplot" after importing the library.
Please suggest on the same.

Comment: Where are the `x` and `y` vectors?

Comment: x and y are array containing "double" and "String" data respectively.